# google sheet, position of first number in a string

Tags: google-sheets

BJ190215P00020000

this is the string. I want to extract the left letters "BJ" (they are from 1 letter up to letters).

I think i need to find the position of the first digit, then apply LEFT function to get out the "BJ". (the letters could be 1-8).

is there a way to find the position of first digit in the string. OR, is there a better way to extract the letters before the first digit?

Answer (score 2):

Try ...

```
=regexextract(A1,"\D+")
```